# visual studio 2017 cordova install android build tools

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2017, build-tools

I have been having a stable set up of Visual Studio 2017 with Apache Cordova for several months till now.

All of a sudden, every thing changed.

Problems are coming at building the application.

It failed with some errors. In the effort of fixing them, Android Studio and SDK and AVD are all updated.

Install Android Build Tools were installed .

I went for VS2017 update.

Then Solutions giving me a message about compatibility with 2015. I have no clue why it is going back to earlier version for a solution created in this version.

Install Android Build Tools were not getting installed.

Why on earth this kind of behavior with Visual Studio?

Any body can throw some light here!! for so many years, I have been using this set up of cordova with android and VS , still the way things are going with it is really nasty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the delay, I know how it feels because I also bumped into all the same issues, then finally returned to VS2015.

About opening a VS2015 project in VS2017, this is not recommended. You should create a new one instead, then manually install all plugins, then import your original www folder.

You may notice that if you change the toolset, it won't be saved next time you open the project. This can be solved by [manually editing your config.xml](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/#toolset_forgotten), then reloading the project.

Most certainly you won't be able to deploy to emulators if you have changed the ANDROID_HOME value from VS2017 to use a newer API than its obsolete API 25. [As you can see here, this issue has no fix](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/#android_home), you can only deal with it by manually deploying to emulator using the CLI.